# Have to kill coreaudio almost every reboot for sound to work

Tags: macos, audio

Recently upon booting my M1 MacBook Air running MacOS 13.3.1 I have to run:

`` sudo kill -9 `ps ax|grep 'coreaudio[a-z]' | awk '{print $1}'` ``

This is not required 100% of the time but at least ~25%

Otherwise no Applications that use sound will work (eg. can't open Safari/Firefox/Apple Music)

I haven't installed any Applications or changed anything recently. Also just updated to 13.3.1 today. Before on 13.2.1 I had the same issue.

Any tips on where to start looking? I have a relatively lean system with only startup applications being small utilities such as Al Dente, Itsycal, Raycast, etc

Comment: Do you have any audio hardware? Are you using headphones? What's the current audio output set to, and what sample rate? Any audio software in use, like Cubase, Logic, etc? TBH, "small utilities" that mess with SystemUIserver etc are often the worst for causing problems.

Comment: @benwiggy Good point, the issue only occurs when connected to my DisplayLink dock. Tried several times since now and then and can reliably only produce when docked.

I use the dock so much it has become second nature I don't even register it as a unique setup. Will file a report with DisplayLink thanks for the pointers